# CakePHP 3.x - Installing Phinx Error

Tags: cakephp, phinx

I am currently studying cakePHP 3.x and I ran into some trouble installing phinx.

```
composer require robmorgan/phinx
```

I keep getting the ff error:

```
Problem 1
- cakephp/migrations 1.8.1 requires robmorgan/phinx 0.8.1 -> satisfiable by robmorgan/phinx[v0.8.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- cakephp/migrations 1.8.1 requires robmorgan/phinx 0.8.1 -> satisfiable by robmorgan/phinx[v0.8.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- cakephp/migrations 1.8.1 requires robmorgan/phinx 0.8.1 -> satisfiable by robmorgan/phinx[v0.8.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- Installation request for cakephp/migrations (locked at 1.8.1, required as ^1.8.0) -> satisfiable by cakephp/migrations[1.8.1].
```

I checked my composer.json file, and changed my cakephp/cakephp require from "3.6.*" to "^3.6" just incase, but I'm still getting this error. I'm trying to install phinx because I'm currently studying cakePHP seeds. Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Kindly ignore the question, I didn't realize that phinx was already installed and I just needed to initialize it to create phinx.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

It is related with cakephp/migrations version, try to update it in `composer.json`.

In my case, I changed it to `"cakephp/migrations": "^2.0.0"`, and it worked fine for me.